# Calling non-static method inside static web-method

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, json.net

In static Web-Method of asp.net how can I call non-static method.

[image]

Comment: Short answer is you can't, make the method you want to call static as well.

Comment: you need an object reference to call a non static method inside a static method

Comment: By the way, show your work and error message as a text, not as an image.

Comment: `string stResponse = a class` looks sick to me.

Comment: You call an instance method by referring to an instance.  Same way you call any instance method anywhere in any system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to understand the difference between "static" and "instance".  And what that means, conceptually, for the operation you're trying to perform.

An instance operation is something that's performed on a *specific instance* of an object.  Falling to the overused car analogies... If you were to perform an operation on your car (drive it, put gas in the tank, crash it, etc.) then you would be performing that operation on *that specific car*.  Not on the general concept of a car, not on all cars, not on all cars of the same type, not even on another completely identical car right next to it.  Just on *that* car.

A static operation isn't associated with a particular instance.  It doesn't apply to a physical construct.  For a car, you might want to do something like look up consumer ratings for a particular make and model.  You're not looking up the ratings for a *specific* car.  Two or more similar enough cars would have the same rating.  You're just looking up information about the *concept* of a car, regardless of any particular physical instance of one.

Now apply this concept to static and instance operations in your code...

In a static operation, you are in the context of the general concept of your class.  There is no specific instance.  So how, conceptually, could you invoke an instance operation?  (When you're looking up the consumer rating of a car, you can't "drive" the consumer rating.  You need an actual car to drive.)

So, regarding your code, you have a number of different approaches:

1. Maybe you need to create an instance within the static operation and perform the instance operation on that instance.
2. Maybe consuming code needs to supply an existing instance to the static operation so it can use that instance.
3. Maybe the instance operation should logically be static.
4. Maybe the static operation should logically be instance-based.

We can't know which of those options makes the most sense.  We can help, if you provide some meaningful context.  But you need to better understand the system you're modeling and what your operations do.

Answer (score 5):

Create an instance of the class you wish to call the method on.

Comment: With this being a web method, the instance of the class is the asp.net web forms page that the web method is defined in. Manually instantiating a web forms page class would likely not be useful.

Comment: I didn't say that the class had to be the web forms page, for example it would be possible to refactor it into a separate class.

Answer (score 3):

Create instance of non-static method

**for example**:

```
public class ABC
{
    public void AB()
    {
    }

    public static void PQ()
    {
         ABC obj= new ABC ();
         obj.AB();
    }
}
```

Comment: U can find it in image. i cant send here as its exceeds characters.

Comment: can you explain UploadEra(loEra,uid) ?
what exactly it working